# Redircting certain path plus anything in it to a 404 and then to the home page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect everything from for example:

```
mycomain.com/ST/My_Dir/anything
```

Where `ST` is equal to a state abbreviation and `anything` is equal to anything.

I tried the below code in my `.htaccess` file but it doesn't work..

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

RedirectMatch 404 ^[a-zA-Z]{2}/My_Dir/.*$
```

Also, is there a way that I can make `My_Dir` case-insensitive? I know how to do this in PHP but just not sure if it's the same here.

Comment: Sorry but you didn't say where do you want to redirect your url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to force specific urls to return 404 response, you can use:

```
RewriteRule ^[A-Z]{2}/My_Dir/.* - [R=404,NC]
```

instead of the `RedirectMatch` rule. Also to throw a 403 Forbidden you can just use `F`

```
RewriteRule ^[A-Z]{2}/My_Dir/.* - [F,NC]
```

In both examples, the `NC` flag makes the match case insensitive. Also I would not recommend using your homepage (/index.php) as your 404 page, better that you make a custom 404.php and set your `ErrorDocument` to that.